# Batch command to archive folders with content using WinRaR

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, compression, archiving

I have lot of folders in the root "C:\Test\Archiv\" (more than 1000).
To be more specific, I get one every hour.
They are named as following : `ay %year% m %month% d %day% h%hour%`

In each folders are 4 files.

What I try to do is to compress all the folders with the files in them in one file.rar.

I tried the command :

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRaR\rar" a -r -ep1 "C:\test.rar" C:\Test\Archiv\ay2015m04d21h*
```

I get correctly my file with the corresponding folders but they are all empty...

So I tried the same command with `"\*.*"`

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRaR\rar" a -r -ep1 "C:\test.rar" C:\Test\Archiv\ay2015m04d21h*\*.*
```

But I get an error "No Files"

Have someone an idea what I could do to get only the folders of the day containing all the files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using wildcards with folders and not files is slightly tricky with WinRAR, but can be done like this:

```
rar a -n*\ay2015m04d21h*\* "C:\test.rar" "C:\Test\Archiv"
```

Comment: Thank you Karan, it helped a lot ! I didn't thought to use the parameter "-n".

 However I still have the full path in my test.rar ...

The rar file contains "Test\Archiv\" then all my Ay2015* folders with my files and I try to get directly Ay2015*\*

I tried to add -ep1 which is good cause Test\ disapear but not Archiv...

I tried -ep but now all my folders disapear...

I don't manage to keep just my Ay*\* folders with my files

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there's any other way to omit all parent folders when you're using wildcards for folders, so `-ep1` is the best you're going to get.

Comment: Ok I see, Thank you, I will look if I keep it like that and deal with it or if I try to go throw loops with several commands. Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks, same to you! If I find a better solution I'll update this answer but so far it doesn't seem possible.